# Why do I see this weird line in my GD pie graph?

Tags: php, gd

Why do I see this weird line in my GD pie graph?

[image: pie graph]

Here's the PHP:

```
<?php
$ratio = $_GET['ratio'];
$height = intval(isset($_GET['size']) ? $_GET['size'] : 200);
$width = intval(isset($_GET['size']) ? $_GET['size'] : 200);
$startDegree = 270;
$ratiodeg = $ratio * 360;
$image = imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height);
imagealphablending($image,false);
imagesavealpha($image,true);
$color = imagecolorallocate($image,127,26,40);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($image,200,200,200);
$transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($image,255,255,255,127);
imagefilledrectangle($image,0,0,$width,$height,$transparent);
if($ratio > 0){
    if($ratio < 1){
        imagefilledarc($image,$width / 2,$height / 2,$width,$height,$ratiodeg + $startDegree,$startDegree,$grey,IMG_ARC_PIE);
    }
    imagefilledarc($image,$width / 2,$height / 2,$width,$height,$startDegree,$ratiodeg + $startDegree,$color,IMG_ARC_PIE);
}
else{
    imagefilledarc($image,$width / 2,$height / 2,$width,$height,$startDegree,360 + $startDegree,$grey,IMG_ARC_PIE);
}
imagefilledellipse($image,$width / 2,$height / 2,$width * 0.95,$height * 0.95,$transparent);
header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: My output]

I ran your code and got this image..

Here are my PHP details

Version: 5.4.3

GD: bundled (2.0.34 compatible)

What ratio are you passing? I used 1, 4, 4.65 (which made a circle with a bit missing) but I never got that line!

Comment: The ratio is a float, but I tried those values as well with the same result. I'm using 5.2.something without GD bundled (at least, I don't think so - I don't have imageantialias which comes bundled so probably not). Could it be a bug with my distribution?

Comment: make a new php file called phpinfo.php and put this in it `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` then run it.. it will give you lots of details about your php, you might want to remove it pretty quick though it's not the most secure page to have on your server!